# ImageMagick cmd to vbs or bat

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

**Question 1:**

For Question 1: 
how to make the following code run in bat file or vbs file?

```
convert *.png -set filename:f "AAAA_%t.png" %[filename:f]
```

it works in command line, but fails in .bat, it shows

```
convert.exe: missing an image filename `AAAA_[filename:f]' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3144.
```

**Question 2:**

Here is the pic:

[image]

I have a B1.png, how can i convert it to four small images? 
Crop the big one to 16 small pieces first then use +append function 4 times to create 4 small pics?
Is there any simple solution to it? How can I achieve it in batch file or vbs file?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What problems are you having? Put the line in a file called *something*.bat and run the code - does it produce an error?

Comment: Hi yes, it shows error. "convert.exe: option requires an argument '-annotate' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/693."

Answer (score 0):

Question 2 can be solved using `convert` command with `crop` operator to divide your image in tiles and then `montage` command to rejoin the tiles in a different order.

You'll have to adjust tile sizes (I used 77x145), but here is a hint on how to proceed:

1. create 16 tiles, one for each cell (images will be named output_00.png, output_01.png and so on):

   ```
   convert B1.png -crop 77x145 +repage +adjoin output_%02d.png
   ```
2. create 4 images, one for each row joining the tiles in the new order (A1,B1,C1,D1) (A2,B2,C2,D2) (A3,B3,C3,D3) (A4,B4,C4,D4):

   ```
   montage -mode concatenate -tile 4x output_00.png output_04.png output_08.png output_12.png S1.png
   montage -mode concatenate -tile 4x output_01.png output_05.png output_09.png output_13.png S2.png
   montage -mode concatenate -tile 4x output_02.png output_06.png output_10.png output_14.png S3.png
   montage -mode concatenate -tile 4x output_03.png output_07.png output_11.png output_15.png S4.png
   ```

If you want to use these commands in a batch file you'll have to escape `%` in the first command, so your batch file should look like this:

```
convert B1.png -crop 77x145 +repage +adjoin output_%%02d.png
montage -mode concatenate -tile 4x output_00.png output_04.png output_08.png output_12.png S1.png
montage -mode concatenate -tile 4x output_01.png output_05.png output_09.png output_13.png S2.png
montage -mode concatenate -tile 4x output_02.png output_06.png output_10.png output_14.png S3.png
montage -mode concatenate -tile 4x output_03.png output_07.png output_11.png output_15.png S4.png
```

more info about crop/tile [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile)

**Notes:**

1. This solution assumes that your "cells" all have the same dimensions
2. It is important to calculate correctly tile sizes (in my example -crop 77x145) otherwise more than 16 images could be generated causing the montage commands to generate wrong results.